# python sqlite3 SELECT and UPDATE causing database locked error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to do something basic, loop through a table and update a field of the rows. However, it gives the error

> "sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked"

It is probably because I'm doing SELECT and UPDATE at the same time. However I have no idea how to do this otherwise.

Below is a bare-bone structure of my code:

**UPDATE**: Updated the code so only connect once. The database locked issue is gone, however the looping is being reset a few times: 001,002,001,002,003,001,002,003

**UPDATE2**: Updated the code again, apparently I missed something with sqlite3. However, the first 2 records still get iterated twice if I do updates in the iteration. So if I comment out the "update" function in the **main**, the iteration goes from 0 to 19. But if I keep it there, it goes like this: 0,1,0,1,2,3,4,...19

```
import sqlite3,time
db_file="testdb.db"
conn=sqlite3.connect(db_file)

def createTables():
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cmd='''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos(
        photo_id CHAR(15) UNIQUE,
        hosted_id CHAR(15)
    );
    '''
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    conn.commit()

    cmd2="INSERT OR IGNORE INTO photos VALUES ('{}','')"

    for i in range(300):
        cursor.execute(cmd2.format(i))
    conn.commit()    

def query(cursor):
    cmd='''
    SELECT * FROM photos
    '''
    return cursor.execute(cmd)

def update(photo_id,hosted_id):
    cmd='''
    UPDATE photos
    SET hosted_id='{hosted_id}'
    WHERE photo_id = '{photo_id}'
    '''.format(**locals())
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    res=cursor.execute(cmd)
    conn.commit()

def getHostedID():
    return "foo"

if __name__=="__main__":
    createTables()
    cur1=conn.cursor()
    query(cur1)
    counter=0
    for i in range(20):
        res=cur1.fetchone()
        hosted_id=counter
        print hosted_id, res[0]
        #This update makes iteration funky
        update(res[0],hosted_id)
        counter=counter+1
```

Comment: Don't reconnect to the database inside every function. Open one connection in `main` and pass it as a an argument to the functions.

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, I did it so to avoid the cursor from being reset. As you can see from the new code, the for loop no longer loops through all records in the correct way anymore.

Comment: What do you mean correct way? Is the order wrong?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, please check my update to the question. With UPDATE, it iterates the first 2 elements twice like this: 0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...

Comment: OK, found the problem, answer lies in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624049/python-sqlite3-cursor-returns-duplicates-when-a-commit-intervenes

Comment: Great. Do you want to answer your own question to help future readers?

Comment: Right, I'll do a bit more investigation and give an answer based on that